# Multisite or MU?

Tags: discussion, wordpress.org

This is more of a definition question than anything. Officially, it's Multisite, but everyone still refers to it as MU. The plugins, the support sites, everything. Even 3/4 of the questions on this site about it refer to it as MU.

Should we care, and if we do, what can we do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I see

[multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite) and [wordpress-mu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-mu) -- since this site is *about* wordpress, I favor merging that into [multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite) perhaps as a synonym.

Ah, never mind, that is already the case

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/multisite/synonyms

So I will complete the merge.

Beyond that **I recommend working "mu" into the body of posts that talk about multisite** for best search coverage, since the tag will be part of the title most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

**mu** has a second meaning: The mu-plugins directory is for **must use** plugins, which cannot be turned off. Plus, it is easier to search for *multisite* than for *mu*. Therefore, the use of a naked **mu** tag should be strongly discouraged, imho.

Comment: Like the one I used, lol